# Connectivity between Flask and Dash Applications

Tags: python, flask, plotly-dash

I am trying to connect a Flask App (as backend) and Dash App (as frontend). For this application I am trying for a number to be inputted by the user through Dash from a dropdown menu so then Flask is able calculate the square of that inputted number and send it back to then be displayed on the webpage. Is this a feasible endeavor?

```
from flask import Flask
from dash import Dash
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_table_experiments as dt
from werkzeug.middleware.dispatcher import DispatcherMiddleware
from werkzeug.serving import run_simple

num_list = [2, 4, 6, 8]

server = Flask(__name__)
dash_app1 = Dash(__name__, server=server, url_base_pathname='/dashboard/')

dash_app1.layout = html.Div([
    html.H1('Hi there, I am app1 for dashboards'),
    html.Div([dcc.Dropdown(id="Number", options=[{'label': i, 'value': i} for i in num_list], value='Numbers')],
    style={'width': '25%', 'display': 'inline-block'}),

    # dcc.Graph(id='number-result'),
    html.Div(id='number-result'),
    ])


@dash_app1.callback(
    Output('number-result', 'children'),
    [Input('Number', 'value')]
)

@server.route('/dashboard/<int:num>')
def render_dashboard(num):
    result = str(num**2)
    return (result, Flask.redirect('/dash1'))

app = DispatcherMiddleware(server, {'dash1': dash_app1.server})

run_simple('0.0.0.0', 8080, app, use_reloader=True, use_debugger=True)
```

One error message that I am getting is:
line 42, in render_dashboard return (result, Flask.redirect('/dash1'))
AttributeError: type object 'Flask' has no attribute 'redirect'

- But I am guessing there are multiple other syntactical mistakes happening here.